# Frequent 504 Gateway timeout

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Lately, we often encounter this 504 Gateway timeout on multiple endpoints

Example of /preview endpoint:

```
Server error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/items/014THVUXPVDHARRLTKGZHI2GLKYADOOZDI/preview` resulted in a `504 Gateway Timeout` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3f981b5d-883 (truncated...)
```

another example on small file upload endpoint:

```
PUT /content?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=rename` resulted in a `504 Gateway Timeout` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "12d80986-9cb (truncated...)
```

Comment: Okay, as with any "gateway timeout" situation, you need to first look at your hardware.  Where are the "gateways" in question?  Then, look at your request patterns and volume.  A "gateway timeout" might be caused by load-shedding.  In any case it is a transient condition that your code must be prepared to handle.

Comment: This is an error happening with microsoft graph api, I've put the tag in the OP, not sure if I should include it in content aswell... Either way this error happens way too often..

Answer (score 1):

Please test the above API calls with [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and see if you can still repro the issue.

Comment: Using the `POST /preview`, I have tried with graph explorer, and I'm unable to get a timeout. At the same time I have tested to get a preview using microsoft graph sdk with a timeout of 5sec, and it times out. I removed the 5sec timeout on the code, but I couldn't get the gateway timeout. It seems to happen randomly. I have many sentry logs regarding this problem though.